# Apply an offset to a camera rotating around an object

Tags: unity, c#

I have a camera that rotates around an object ***to simulate the rotation of this object.***
To do this, I simply move my camera to the object before making my rotation and then translate it back:

```
void Update()
{
        distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(camera.transform.position, myObject.center);
        transform.position = myObject.center;

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, horizontalRotationValue);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, verticalRotationValue);

        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, 0f, -distanceToTarget));

        centeredPosition = transform.localPosition;
        ...
```

My problem comes from the fact that I would like to also be able to have an offset of the view of my camera in relation to the object. All this while continuing to simulate the rotation of my object by rotating the camera around.

[image: camera offset]
After my current rotation logic, the object is still in the center of the view.
So at the first iteration of my rotation, I save the difference between the centered position on the model and the offset camera.
`offsetToCenter = transform.localPosition - centeredPosition;`

So, I hope to be able to use this offset to shift my camera again after it has rotated.
However, the recorded offset no longer corresponds to the offset on the local space of the camera since it has rotated.
`transform.localPosition += transform.localRotation * offsetToCenterPosition;`

The rotation works well but not the position. There is a step that I must be doing wrong or that is missing. I think it comes from the conversion of `offsetToCenterPosition` with the new rotation of my camera.

Comment: Did you try `offsetToCenter = Quaternion.Inverse(transform.localRotation) * (transform.localPosition - centeredPosition);` ?

Comment: This is indeed what I was missing ! Thanks a lot

Comment: Want to write up your solution as an Answer below?

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed coming from the `offsetToCenterPosition` calculation. Thank you DMGregory.

Here is the full answer:

```
void Update()
    {
        distanceToTarget = Vector3.Distance(camera.transform.position, myObject.center);

        transform.position = myObject.center;

        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, horizontalRotationValue);
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.right, verticalRotationValue);

        transform.Translate(new Vector3(0f, 0f, -distanceToTarget));

        centeredPosition = transform.localPosition;

        transform.localPosition += transform.localRotation * offsetToCenterPosition;
    }

void UpdateOffsetToCenterPosition() //called on first iteration
    {
        offsetToCenterPosition = Quaternion.Inverse(transform.localRotation) * (transform.localPosition - centeredPosition);
    }
```